# How can I create a Custom Gauge Field which is better looking?

Tags: blackberry

I need to create a custom gauge field which looks slimmer like a Blue thin line filling in.
Any ideas/resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any native BlackBerry controls, but you can create your own custom field and implement a paint() method that draws the gauge using Graphics.fillRoundRect().